# How can I sum up the values in lists within lists in Haskell?

Tags: list, haskell, sum

As I try to learn Haskell just for fun and the experience I have no other possibility than to ask you the "dumb" questions of a total beginner ^^.
I stumbled across the problem how it might be possible to find the sums of lists whithin lists e.g. [[1,3],[4,7],[2,5]] = [4,11,7] and I have found no solution so far. Does anybody have a clue how this might work in Haskell?

Comment: Assuming you know how to sum one list, take a look at `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.

Comment: No clue at all, this sounds way to difficult, doubt anybody has ever done something like that. ...Seriously, what have you actually tried? Have you [read](https://wiki.haskell.org/Books#Textbooks) any bit of introduction? I always recommend [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/), it's great for a light start.

Comment: (No offense intended – Haskell sure can seem confusing at first, but with a bit of introductory material I'm sure you will get along. But asking for tiny examples like this is not effective, not for you and certainly not for StackOverflow.)

Comment: I am used to imperative languages like java and it has been only a week since I first read through learn you a haskell... i have not seen map to be used like this before, so thanks for the tip

Comment: Check out Haskell list comprehensions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about function types, it may help.

You have `[[Int]]` and you want a function `[[Int]] -> [Int]` to get `[Int]`

The function you want is `map sum :: [[Int]] -> [Int]`

The following codes was run in `ghci`

First you have list of list of ints. Note that in this example you need to guide `ghci` with `[[Int]]` to get the type you want instead of the confusing generic `[[1,3],[4,7],[2,5]] :: Num t => [[t]]`

```
Prelude> let xs = [[1,3],[4,7],[2,5]] :: [[Int]]
```

Next, you might already know `sum`, let make one that specific for `[Int]` instead of generic `sum :: (Foldable t, Num a) => t a -> a`, this will make the type easier to read

```
Prelude> let sumInts = sum :: [Int] -> Int
```

Next, let test the `sumInts` on some element of `xs = [[1,3],[4,7],[2,5]]`

```
Prelude> :t sumInts [1,3]
sumInts [1,3] :: Int
Prelude> sumInts [1,3]
4
```

Now you can do `sum` on an element of a list, to do that to entire list you can use `map`

```
Prelude> :t map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

Let see if you pass `sumInts` to a map what type you will get?

```
Prelude> :t map sumInts 
map sumInts :: [[Int]] -> [Int]
```

This should work with `xs :: [[Int]]` but let check type first to make sure

```
Prelude> :t map sumInts xs
map sumInts xs :: [Int]
```

Now do the computation

```
Prelude> map sumInts xs
[4,11,7]
```

Since `sumInts = sum` , this also mean `sum` would work too

```
Prelude> :t map sum xs
map sum xs :: [Int]
Prelude> map sum xs
[4,11,7]
```

Note 1: `map sum` real type is `map sum :: (Foldable t, Num b) => [t b] -> [b]`) in the last example it was inferred by type `[[Int]]` of xs to `[[Int]] -> [Int]`

Answer (score 1):

You can sum a list with `sum` and you can apply any function to each element of a list with `map` so the function you are looking for is:

```
map sum
```

when you apply the function:

```
map sum [[1,3],[4,7],[2,5]]
```

you get your `[4,11,7]`. What happens is that map *walks* over the outer list and keeps applying the function that it gets as its first argument (in this case it is the `sum` function) to every element. At the same time, `map` collects the results in an output list. So `sum` is applied to `[1,3]` with the result `4` to `[4,7]` with the result `11` and to `[2,5]` with the result `7`, all of which are placed in a list `[4,11,7]`.

Comment: if you are satisfied with the answer (or any other) please accept it to close this question